# Can we concatenate string and observable value and pass as input parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, string-interpolation

I have a child component which expecting a string input parameter from its parent. From the parent I want to pass an observable along with additional string data.
How can we do this without setting value from component.ts ? Need to do something like this in component.html
<Child [inputparam] = " something {{obs$|async}} something more ">
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly as you describe it.

Define in your Parent Component an Observable and a string

```
myObservable: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
myString = '';
```

Pass it to your Child Component

```
<child-component [myObservable]="myObservable" [myString]="myString"></child-component>
```

And in your Child Component you wait for those values to be passed.

```
@Input() myObservable: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
@Input() myString = '';
```

That's actually it.

The observable works among both components now.

**Variant 2 :: grouped**

When you want to put it all in one you have to define an object.

```
class AllTogether {
    myObservable: BehaviorSubject<string>;
    myString: string;
}
```

Instantiate it in your parent component

```
allTogether = new AllTogether();
allTogether.myObservable = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
allTogether.myString = '';
```

Pass it to your Child Component

```
<child-component [allTogether]="allTogether"></child-component>
```

And in your Child Component you wait for the object to be passed.

```
class AllTogether {
    myObservable: BehaviorSubject<string>;
    myString: string;
}

@Input() allTogether = new AllTogether();
```

And then access the values

```
this.allTogether.myObservable.subscribe( /* do something */)
```

Comment: Thank you @Lynx let me try that.Cant we combine both this observable and string together.{{ string val + obs$ | async }}

Comment: Not with curlies, but you could make an input that accepts multiple values like [myStuff]="{str: myString, obs: (myObs | async)}"

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: @Lynx and Mike , Thanks a lot .you are the best.Not sure how long it wil take me to  think like you guys.I don't have enough points to up vote also.Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear that.  Could you please mark my answer as solution?